# Prove that polynomials L(x) have degree n, satisfying L(x)=1 and L(x sub j)=0 whenever i is not equal to one.

Tags: numerical-methods

For this question I basically need to prove the properties of Lagrange interpolation using basis functions. I understand the exsistence of an identiy matrix causes for us to have these properties but I am unsure how to go about proving it.

Comment: [Your question should be clear without the title](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10144/42969). After the title has drawn someone's attention to the question by giving a good description, its purpose is done. The title is not the first sentence of your question, so make sure that the question body does not rely on specific information in the title.

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).